# Type Mismatch while returning Map(String,java.sql.Date)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have recently started to work with Spark-Scala and now I am facing a issue which might be too trivial and basic but I am not able to catch it .

AIM -

I have a function which should take `dateTime:String` and should return a `Map(String,java.sql.Date)`.

Code -

```
def newgetWeekStartDate(dateTime:String,mode:String):Map[String,java.sql.Date] = {

    mode match {
      case ExecMode.incremental =>

        logInfo(s" ****************** ACCESSING TIMEUTILS IN INCREMENTAL MODE ******************")
        val currentWeek = weekStartDate.getWeekStartDate(dateTime)
        val weekRelatedInformationMap = Map("currentWeek" -> currentWeek)
        weekRelatedInformationMap
      //        getWeekStartDate(dateTime)

      case ExecMode.full =>
        logInfo(s" ****************** ACCESSING TIMEUTILS in FULL MODE i.e 90 Days ******************")
        val sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -90)
        val quarterDate = sdfOutput.format(cal.getTime())
        val rangeWeek = weekStartDate.getWeekStartDate(quarterDate)
        val currentWeek = weekStartDate.getWeekStartDate(dateTime)

        val formattedCurrentWeek = Date.valueOf(currentWeek)
        val formattedRangeWeek = Date.valueOf(rangeWeek)


        val weekRelatedInformationMap1 = Map("currentWeek" -> formattedCurrentWeek,
          "rangeWeek" -> formattedRangeWeek).withDefaultValue("NONE")

        weekRelatedInformationMap1

    }
  }
```

Now when I am returning the Map, I am getting this error -

```
[ERROR] .............. \src\main\scala\com\eg\modulename\utils\utils.scala:50: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String <: Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.
Serializable]
```

UPDATE -

This is how I am planning on calling this function -

```
val crrntWeek = utils.newgetWeekStartDate(utils.currentDate,"incremental").getOrElse("currentWeek","currentWeek Not Found")
```

This will then be used like this -

```
val existingDF = reader.readFrmHive(ConfigUtils.existingPath).filter(to_date(col("datetime"),"yyyy-MM-dd") >= crrntWeek
```

Complete Stack Trace -

```
    C:\Users\patrag\Documents\Git_REpo\new-winnew-update>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.eg.modulename:winnew-update:jar:0.1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 112, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 138, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building winnew-update 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ winnew-update ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\patrag\Documents\Git_REpo\new-winnew-update\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:prepare-agent (default) @ winnew-update ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\patrag\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.5\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\patrag\\Documents\\Git_REpo\\new-windows-softwar
e-update\\target\\jacoco.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ winnew-update ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ winnew-update ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) @ winnew-update ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.11.0
[WARNING]  com.twitter:chill_2.11:0.9.3 requires scala version: 2.11.12
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.java,**/*.scala,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] C:\Users\patrag\Documents\Git_REpo\new-winnew-update\src\main\scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 22 source files to C:\Users\patrag\Documents\Git_REpo\new-winnew-update\target\classes at 1592903601259
[ERROR] C:\Users\patrag\Documents\Git_REpo\new-winnew-update\src\main\scala\com\eg\modulename\utils\utils.scala:50: error: type mismatch;
[INFO]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String <: Comparable[_ >: java.util.Date with String <: java.io.Serializable] with java.io.Serializable] with java.io.
Serializable]
[INFO]  required: Map[String,String]
[INFO]         weekRelatedInformationMap1
[INFO]         ^
[WARNING] C:\Users\patrag\Documents\Git_REpo\new-winnew-update\src\main\scala\com\eg\modulename\writer\BaseWriter.scala:3: warning: imported `Writer' is permanently hidden by definition of trait Write
r in package writer
[INFO] import com.eg.modulename.writer.Writer
[INFO]                                 ^
[WARNING] one warning found
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.915 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-23T14:43:26+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/620M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.15.2:compile (default) on project winnew-update: wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exi
t value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: need calling method code and and full stacktrace

Comment: At a glance you're somehow returning a "mixed" type - that `java.util.Date with String` hints that it might be either a String or Date. My guess is that `weekStartDate.getWeekStartDate(dateTime)` returns `String`, and then it is returned as is in the `ExecMode.incremental` branch, but parsed into Date in the `ExecMode.full` branch

Comment: @SomeshwarKale, I have added the stack trace and calling of this function.

Comment: @J0HN, I also tried with java.sql.Date, still no luck. I have updated the same in the description too. You are correct  `weekStartDate.getWeekStartDate(dateTime)` returns `String`. I am then converting it in `Date` format so that I can use it in a `filter` on a Dataframe.

Comment: Yuo're only converting it to `Date` in one code path, but not in the other. And then you're also trying to do `withDefaultValue("NONE")`, which tries to put a default value of string to a map with Date. And in your calling code you plan to `getOrElse` to a String again. You should probably just trust the compiler and either always return a string, or always return a date - Scala is a strongly typed language, so it doesn't allow tricks like that (i.e. no implicit convertion to string, cannot declare variable/return type to be one and then use as if it is something else, etc.)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`,  `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V., I will try it out and share my findings soon. Thanks again for recommending best practice for date manipulations. But I am really curious how  `java.sql.Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` etc can cause trouble, if you can state an example it will be great be a lesson learnt  for me. I would like to reproduce it too.

Comment: [Here](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) and [here](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue and the Error should have been self explanatory.
Thanks @JOHN, for help me out here.

The only issue was -

When i am defining the return type to be of Type `Map[String,java.sql.Date]` then, in the return , i shouldn't have added .withDefaultValue("NONE") because -

If there is no Input, then it would have picked up the default value which was `NONE` i.e `String`.

So, The above mentioned change, fixed the issue.
[image]

O/P -
[image]

************* UPDATED ANSWER ****************

As per the recommendation @Ole V.V.

I have replaced the usage of `Calendar`, `java.sql.Date`,`SimpleDateFormat`.

```
def getWeekStartDate(dateTime:String):String =
    {
      logInfo(s"********* INSIDE getWeekStartDate FUNCTION ************** Input DateTime - $dateTime")

      val setSimpleDateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")

      val dayOfWeek = LocalDate.parse(dateTime,setSimpleDateFormat).getDayOfWeek

      if (dayOfWeek != DateTimeConstants.MONDAY)
        {
          val new_date = LocalDate.parse(dateTime).plusDays(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY - dayOfWeek.getValue()).toString
          val firstDayOfTheWeek:String = new_date.format(setSimpleDateFormat)
          firstDayOfTheWeek
        }
      else
        {
          val new_date = dateTime
          val firstDayOfTheWeek:String = new_date.format(setSimpleDateFormat)
          firstDayOfTheWeek
        }
    }



def newgetWeekStartDate(dateTime:String,mode:String):Map[String,java.time.LocalDate] = {

    mode match {
      case ExecMode.incremental =>

        logInfo(s" ****************** ACCESSING TIMEUTILS IN INCREMENTAL MODE ******************")
        val currentWeek = weekStartDate.getWeekStartDate(dateTime)
        val formattedCurrentWeek = LocalDate.parse(currentWeek)
        val weekRelatedInformationMap = Map("currentWeek" -> formattedCurrentWeek)
        weekRelatedInformationMap
      //        getWeekStartDate(dateTime)

      case ExecMode.full =>
        logInfo(s" ****************** ACCESSING TIMEUTILS in FULL MODE i.e 90 Days ******************")
        val sdfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
        val cal = LocalDateTime.now()

        val rangeWeek = weekStartDate.getWeekStartDate(cal.plusMonths(-3).format(sdfOutput))
        val currentWeek = weekStartDate.getWeekStartDate(cal.format(sdfOutput))

        val formattedCurrentWeek = LocalDate.parse(currentWeek)
        val formattedRangeWeek = LocalDate.parse(rangeWeek)

        val weekRelatedInformationMap = Map("currentWeek" -> currentWeek,
          "rangeWeek" -> rangeWeek).withDefaultValue("NONE")

        val weekRelatedInformationMap1 = Map("currentWeek" -> formattedCurrentWeek,
          "rangeWeek" -> formattedRangeWeek)

        weekRelatedInformationMap1

    }
```

Does this look like good Implementation ?